# Aggregate sequencing/mapping/etc. metrics from cellranger across Illumina samples

Tags: scrnaseq, cellranger

I have a number of single-cell projects processed with [cellranger from 10x Genomics](https://support.10xgenomics.com/single-cell-gene-expression/software/pipelines/latest/what-is-cell-ranger). The pipeline produces a number of handy metrics that are summarized for each Illumina sample in [web page](https://support.10xgenomics.com/single-cell-gene-expression/software/pipelines/latest/output/summary). These include things like the estimated number of cells, the fraction of reads in cells, and mapping rates. What I would like is to aggregate this information from multiple Illumina samples into a single file. [MultiQC](http://multiqc.info/) is the obvious choice for such a task, but it appears that no one has written a module to process cellranger data for it. Are there any other prepackaged ways to perform this aggregation?

If there's no convenient tool for this I'll just write a MultiQC module, but I'd obviously like to avoid the extra effort unless it's really needed.

Comment: Single-cell RNA-seq analysis is still developing (not crystallized yet), so I think what you want is not there yet. If you think it may be handy for your analysis, many more may follow, so making a tool for this might be fruitful (if you make it available for others).

Comment: We’ve written a MultiQC module for Supernova, but not Long ranger or Cell Ranger (yet). I agree that one would be useful, and probably quite quick to write if there’s also a JSON summary file output for that tool too. We’ve been talking about this recently. Did you ever get anywhere with writing a new module?

Comment: any new about that? The cellranger is now version 5 and produce still data that would be great to compile in a single report.

Comment: Things move fast.  Cellranger now has a version 6.0

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple script to do it. Not sure whether that's what you want.

````
#!/bin/bash
#CellrangerSummary.sh Sample1 Sample2
csvtool transpose $1/outs/*summary.csv | csvcut -c 1 > summary.csv
for sample in "$@"
    do
        csvtool transpose $sample/outs/*summary.csv > tempfilesforcsvtool.$sample
        csvjoin -c 1 summary.csv tempfilesforcsvtool.$sample > temp2
    mv temp2 summary.csv
rm tempfilesforcsvtool.$sample
    done

csvformat -T summary.csv > summary.tsv
rm summary.csv
```
````